# How to reflect 1 or 0 based on data on other cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, vlookup, flatten

In the range of A1:W14, I have the delivery data. Based on the data, I have to check the performance within the range A18:W31. In Delivery performance table, Dispatch Column, I need to bring the dispatch volume from the Delivery Data table. That can be done by doing cell linking but considering the dynamic data changes in Delivery performance table I can not do that.

Based on SLA column, the performance will be reflected accordingly. Here, D-0 means the delivery on the dispatched day. D+1 is the next day of dispatch and D+2 is the 2nd Next day of dispatch.

If the SLA of a customer is D-0 and they receive products as per SLA, value of D-0 on the dispatched day will be 1 else 0. For instance, AAA's products dispatched on 1st Jan and AAA received on the same day as per SLA, so the value of D-0 on 1st Jan is 1 (cell E22). In another example, BBB's product volume is 200 and dispatched on 1st Jan. As per SLA, delivery was supposed to be done on same day but delivered on next day (i.e. D+1) of dispatch. So the value of D-0 on 1st Jan is 0 (Cell E23).

As an exceptional example, III's ordered volume 200 unit was dispatched on 1st Jan. As per SLA, the order was supposed to deliver on 2nd Jan (D+1). But due to efficiency and urgency, it was delivered on D-0. In that case, performance will be 1.

I am trying to replace the value by using formula or any automated ways. To get the spreadsheet, [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FFQipnDEwRZ7oO4n2ATxlUxvbbttCgZ9L2bMCRuaAZk/edit#gid=0).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E22:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(" ×", REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))&
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF((1*REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0), ROW(D5:D14)&"×"&D5:D14&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0)+D1, ), 
 FLATTEN(IF(FILTER(D5:$W14, D3:$W3="delivery")="",,
 FILTER(ROW(D5:D14)&"×"&D5:$W14&"×"&D1:$W1, D3:$W3="delivery"))), 1, 0))),,
 9^9)))="", 0, 1), "×", 1))
```

---

J22:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(" ×", REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))&
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF((1*REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0), ROW(H5:H14)&"×"&H5:H14&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0)+H1, ), 
 FLATTEN(IF(FILTER(H5:$W14, H3:$W3="delivery")="",,
 FILTER(ROW(H5:H14)&"×"&H5:$W14&"×"&H1:$W1, H3:$W3="delivery"))), 1, 0))),,
 9^9)))="", 0, 1), "×", 1))
```

---

etc.

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(" ×", REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))&
 IF(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF((1*REGEXEXTRACT($C5:$C14, "\d+"))>=
 SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0), ROW(D5:D14)&"×"&D5:D14&"×"&SEQUENCE(1, 4, 0)+D1, ), 
 FLATTEN(IF(FILTER(D5:$W14, D3:$W3="delivery")="",,
 FILTER(ROW(D5:D14)&"×"&D5:$W14&"×"&D1:$W1, D3:$W3="delivery"))), 1, 0))),,
 9^9)))="", 0&REPT(" ×", VLOOKUP(ROW(C5:C14)&"×"&F5:F14, SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(FILTER(D5:$W14, D3:$W3="delivery")="",,
 FILTER(ROW(D5:D14)&"×"&D5:$W14&"¤"&D1:$W1, D3:$W3="delivery"))), "¤"), 2, 0)-D1)&1, 1), "×", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for responding late. Your solution brings the output that I was trying to reflect. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Hi Player0, Just a simple query, in the solution if the delivery is not done as per SLA (D_0,D+1 etc), it reflected the value zero. Is it possible to reflect 1 on th Day from the delivery? For example SLA of AAA is D-0. But if it is delivered on D+1, "1" will be reflected on the cell of delivery column of respective date so that I can track all the order to check when it was delivered and when it was supposed to be. Thanks.

Comment: @ShazzadKabir answer updated